# npm install fails because of chown

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have installed npm locally in `~/.local`
Now, I want to install grunt-cli globally in this local install, but I have this output :

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-18-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/etud/(my name)/.local/usr/bin/node" "/home/etud/(my name)/.local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "grunt-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.1.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.4
npm ERR! path /home/etud/(my name)/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.13/package/package.json.ee5c5aa03b9d2c7367d767e1d6e17af3
npm ERR! code Unknown system error -121
npm ERR! errno -121
npm ERR! syscall chown

npm ERR! Unknown system error -121: Unknown system error -121, chown '/home/etud/(my name)/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.13/package/package.json.ee5c5aa03b9d2c7367d767e1d6e17af3'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/etud/(my name)/npm-debug.log
```

I've done :

```
$> npm config set -g user=`whoami`
```

and put this into `~/.npmrc` :

```
root =    /home/(my name)/.local/lib/node_modules
binroot = /home/(my name)/.local/bin
manroot = /home/(my name).local/share/man
```

Any idea ?

**EDIT**
I'm on my university machine that are working on nfs systems. It seems I can't call the chown command because of problem of user map.

Is there a way to make npm skip any chown ?

Comment: Tnx for `npm config set -g user=`whoami``